# How to Pause Before Performing an Action

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have the need to place a quick pause in my application before performing an action (enabling an application bar button), but I am unsure of how to best accomplish this. Basically a lot of processing is happening in another thread but then the UI is updated. Once the UI is updated, I am scrolling a pivot control to a particular pivot item. I would like to pause for about 1 second, or however long it takes to scroll to the previous pivot item in the pivot control, before allowing the application bar button to be enabled. How might I accomplish this? What I have so far is as follows

```
// Show image and scroll to start page if needed
if (Viewport != null)
{
    Viewport.Source = result;
    if (editPagePivotControl != null && editPagePivotControl.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
    //Here is where the pivot control is told to move to the first item
    // (from the second which it will be on before this happens)
        editPagePivotControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    //A flag to determine whether the app bar button should be enabled
    //How to pause for the time it takes to finish moving
    // to the first pivot item?         
    if (_wasEdited)
        ((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0]).IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: [`System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(/*milliseconds to wait*/);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx)

Comment: @sam oh lawd no.  Just use a dispatcher timer to put off execution for a specific amount of time.  Or, better yet, figure out how to tell when it is done moving.

Comment: @Will Well there's always [timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx), but I don't think it would be worth it in the OP's situation.

Comment: @Sam: He'd have to sleep on a different thread.  Sleeping on the UI thread would just block what he's waiting for.

Comment: What is the comparison between using Thread.Sleep as opposed to a timer? And how would I do the best option?

Comment: @Will Ah yes, I assumed it was already on a different thread.lol (must of missed that)

Comment: @Matthew Well it depends on the situation. IMO, I would suggest creating a separate thread then call `Thread.Sleep()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, using [System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx):

```
if (_wasEdited)
{
   DispatcherTimer t = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Normal, Dispatcher);
   t.Tick += new EventHandler((o,e) => 
     ((ApplicationBarIconButton)ApplicationBar.Buttons[0]).IsEnabled = true;
   t.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000);
   t.Start();
}
```

This will wait for 1000 milliseconds, then come back to the UI thread (since we set `Dispatcher` in the `DispatcherTimer` constructor) and enable your application bar.

If you do this a lot, consider making the timer a member of the class.